# How to increment an amount up to 120?

Tags: javascript

i have this function and can change the value between 1 and 2.
How to change this function to increment up to 120? (120 is limit)

```
const decrementAmount = () => {
   let newAmount = Amount - 1;
   if (newAmount < 1) {
     newAmount = 1;
   }
   setAmount(newAmount);
 };

 const incrementAmount = () => {
   let newAmount = Amount + 1;
   if (newAmount > 2) {
     newAmount = 2;
   }
   setAmount(newAmount);
 };
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you want to get, but replacing all **2** by **120** would be the obvious approach to me, since it is currently **2**.

Comment: So you have those methods and you know that the current limit is `2`. And you're asking how to change those functions to make the limit `120`? Is that right? If that's what you're asking, then please read the code and try to tell us where the limit of `2` is applied in your code.

Comment: This is harmless, but as a small warning: Please make sure you understand code you are given/find on the internet before using it. Copy-pasting without a good understanding of what's happening is how you build, at best, unmaintainable code, or at worst, actively malicious code.

Comment: Actually i build it by myself. 
I let the amount increase +1 when i press the button. It works. So the new amount is 2. 
If i want to decrease the amount -1, i set the new amount to 1.
That's why i'm asking. I still don't understand, what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I got it!
i changed my limit: "newAmount = 20;"

```
const decrementAmount = () => {
    let newAmount = Amount - 1;
    if (newAmount < 1) {
      newAmount = 1;
    }
    setAmount(newAmount);
  };

  const incrementAmount = () => {
    let newAmount = Amount + 1;
    if (newAmount > 20) {
      newAmount = 20;
    }
    setAmount(newAmount);
  };
```

Comment: You could just delete the question since this is not a reoccuring issue and none else will likely ever encounter it the same way.

Comment: This does not accurately answer your question tho. Also be aware that a nice answer contains a description of what the issue was and how you solved it. Not just a chunck of code. Be aware that this is supposed to be a respository.